# integer array won't print

Tags: java, arrays, prng

I created this method `randomInt`, that gives a random number, between -5, and 15. I created another method `randomIntArray` that calls `randomInt`, in a loop, and stores the random integers into an array. However, when I try to print it, it just returns an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`.

```
public static int randomInt(int low, int high) {
    double e;
    double x = Math.random();
    e = low + x * (high - low);
    return (int) e;
}

public static int[] randomIntArray(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt(-5, 15); //"-5&15 are the lower and upper bounds of the random number array
    }
    return a;
}
```

In `randomInt`, When I didn't cast the return value into an `int`, it worked, however I need it to return an `int` for the array to work.

Comment: Can you show us the code where you print the array out and give us the stack trace..

Comment: I do not believe that the code shown will produce an `OutOfBoundsException`. There must be a bug in the code to print the contents of the array, which you have not shown. Please add that code to the question. :-)

Comment: The problem is probably in your printing routine. Try using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(randomIntArray(n)))` to print and see if you still get the error.

Answer (score 2):

Check your printing code after calling randomIntArray(number);

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[]args) {
    int[] myArray = randomIntArray(10);

    // Manual iteration through your array
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.length; i++) {
        System.out.print(myArray[i] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println("");

    // Use of Arrays class to print your array
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(myArray));
} 

public static int randomInt(int low, int high) {
    double e;
    double x = Math.random();
    e = low + x * (high - low);
    return (int) e;
}

public static int[] randomIntArray(int n) {
    int[] a = new int[n];
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
        a[i] = randomInt(-5, 15);
    }//"-5&15 are the lower and upper bounds of the random number array
    return a;
}
```

Results:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

http://ideone.com/3OrTei

In the function calling randomIntArray(int n):

```
int[] array = randomIntArray(5);
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    System.out.println(array[i]);
}
```

The code works, just make sure you're printing the results properly